# using Python Merge two json file with each file having multiple json objects

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, object, merge

I am very new to Python, I need to merge two json file with multiple json object based on **"Id"**.

File1.json

```js
{"id": 1, "name": "Ault", "class": 8, "email": "ault@pynative.com"}
{"id": 2, "name": "john", "class": 8, "email": "jhon@pynative.com"}
{"id": 3, "name": "josh", "class": 8, "email": "josh@pynative.com"}
{"id": 4, "name": "emma", "class": 8, "email": "emma@pynative.com"}
```

File2.json

```js
{"id": 4, "math": "A", "class": 8, "physics": "D"}
{"id": 2, "math": "B", "class": 8, "physics": "C"}
{"id": 3, "math": "A", "class": 8, "physics": "A"}
{"id": 1, "math": "C", "class": 8, "physics": "B"}
```

I have tried both **json.loads(jsonObj)** and **json.load(path)**. Both throw errors.
I know both files are not a valid json as a whole (combined), but each line in a file is a valid json. I want to read line by line and merge both.

Comment: `list1 = [json.loads(line) for line in open(path)]` and then you can post your attempt at merging (hint: plenty of questions on merging dicts here on SO)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can read line by line then parse

```py
# asuming

# File1.json

# {"id": 1, "name": "Ault", "class": 8, "email": "ault@pynative.com"}
# {"id": 2, "name": "john", "class": 8, "email": "jhon@pynative.com"}
# {"id": 3, "name": "josh", "class": 8, "email": "josh@pynative.com"}
# {"id": 4, "name": "emma", "class": 8, "email": "emma@pynative.com"}

# File2.json

# {"id": 4, "math": "A", "class": 8, "physics": "D"}
# {"id": 2, "math": "B", "class": 8, "physics": "C"}
# {"id": 3, "math": "A", "class": 8, "physics": "A"}
# {"id": 1, "math": "C", "class": 8, "physics": "B"}


import json
merged = {}

with open('File1.json') as f:
    for line in f:
        jsonified = json.loads(line)
        merged[jsonified['id']] = jsonified
        
with open('File2.json') as f:
    for line in f:
        jsonified = json.loads(line)
        merged[jsonified['id']].update(jsonified) # asuming both file has same ids otherwise use try catch

merged = list(merged.values())
print(merged)
```

```
[{'id': 1,
  'name': 'Ault',
  'class': 8,
  'email': 'ault@pynative.com',
  'math': 'C',
  'physics': 'B'},
 {'id': 2,
  'name': 'john',
  'class': 8,
  'email': 'jhon@pynative.com',
  'math': 'B',
  'physics': 'C'},
 {'id': 3,
  'name': 'josh',
  'class': 8,
  'email': 'josh@pynative.com',
  'math': 'A',
  'physics': 'A'},
 {'id': 4,
  'name': 'emma',
  'class': 8,
  'email': 'emma@pynative.com',
  'math': 'A',
  'physics': 'D'}]
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is my take on this using [pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/).

```
import pandas as pd
import os

os.chdir(os.getcwd())
file_path_1 = 'file1.json'
file_path_2 = 'file2.json'

df1 = pd.read_json(file_path_1, lines=True)
df2 = pd.read_json(file_path_2, lines=True)

df = df1.merge(df2, on='id')

print(df)
```

Output:

```
   id  name  class_x              email math  class_y physics
0   1  Ault        8  ault@pynative.com    C        8       B
1   2  john        8  jhon@pynative.com    B        8       C
2   3  josh        8  josh@pynative.com    A        8       A
3   4  emma        8  emma@pynative.com    A        8       D
```